# PhpStorm glue together signs

Tags: phpstorm, settings, phpstorm-2017.2

I can't find how to make

```
=> == === != !== ect.
```

looks like one sign in `phpstorm`

Could some one help me to find this settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called "ligatures" and can be enabled in:

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | Color Schema | Color Schema Font` (or maybe just `Editor | Font` -- I'm not 100% sure what this new settings page does exactly)
3. `Enable font ligatures` option.

Obviously, you need to have fonts that support such symbols installed on your computer/OS.

Looks like *only Fira Code is bundled* with the IDE and other supported fonts you may need to install manually -- see below.

---

From https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/06/phpstorm-2016-2-eap-162-646/

> **Support for ligatures in editor**
>
> PhpStorm now supports fonts with programming ligatures, like [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode), [Monoid](http://larsenwork.com/monoid/) or [Hasklig](https://github.com/i-tu/Hasklig).